# Greatest number you can write using 3 symbols of a standard keyboard.

Tags: soft-question

Light problem. I think I have two possible answers: $9^9!$ or is $9^{9!}$ greater ? Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a calculator that can display either answer.

Is there something that is totally different that is larger ?

Happy holidays!

Comment: How about $9!!$?

Comment: The above sounds like I'm very excited.

Comment: You can just define $A$ to be an incredibly large number. So no such number exists.

Comment: @JetChung Did you mean $(9!)!$ ? This is smaller than $9^9!$ because $9!\lt 9^9$. I've also seen double factorial to mean "skip every other number" I.e. $9!!=9\cdot 7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$, which is even smaller.

Comment: What about $9^{9^9}$?

Comment: Mathematica gives $9^9!\sim 7\times 10^{3158983320}$, making it the largest number mentioned here, by far.

Comment: @StinkingBishop ah, you're right. I blame my painkillers...

Comment: @Infinity_hunter $9^{9^9}$ is smaller than $9^9!$ because it's the product of $9^9$ nines, while $9^9!$ is the product of $9^9$ numbers, most of which are larger than $9$.

Comment: using the gamma function definition of  ! we have that -1! $= \infty$

Comment: You have to admit using Gamma is creative. With minimal introduction: 1/0
Or (the triple exponent, that I seem unable to write):
∞^∞^∞
Although mabe infinity is only available on foreign keyboards. I think I remember seeing it on a Selectric Ball on an electric typewriter back in the 70's.

Comment: Hold down the <ALT> key and hit the sequence 236 on the numeric keypad and you get ∞ :)

Answer (score 1):

Using tetration, you can get quite a large number. ${^{n}a}$ is defined as ${{a^a}^a}^{...}$. In other words, it is repeated exponentiation.

Therefore, using just ^, 9, 9 you can get:

${^{9}9}$

which is veeeery big.

Answer (score 1):

If we allow tetration notation, then $\displaystyle {}^{{}^{9}9}9$ is larger than the other suggestions.
For clarity's sake. this means an iterated exponentiation of the form $$9^{9^{9^{.^{.^{.}}}}}$$ where the height of the tower is $$9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9}}}}}}}}}$$
I'm not sure what this looks like in standard form, however.

Answer (score 0):

You will need logarithms for this; Stirling's approximation gives
$$ \log n! = n \log n -n + \frac{1}{2} \log 2 \pi n + \frac{1}{12n} + \frac{1}{288n^2}  - O(n^{-3} )$$
so we get
$$  \log 9^{9^9}  = 9^9 \log 9,$$

$$  \log 9^9! \approx 9^9 (9 \log 9 - 1 )  $$
which is larger

Put briefly
$$ 9^9 \log 9^9 = 9^9 \cdot 9 \log 9 = 9^{10} \log 9 $$

Answer (score 0):

Well, $9^9!$ is a product of $9^9$ terms ($1, 2, 3, ...$), $9^9 - 9$ of which are greater than $9$. Since $9^9 - 9 > 9!$, $$9^9! > 9^{9!}$$